# I am not able to run this code on Code::blocks IDE but works fine online...!!can anyone tell me what modifications i should to get it working on IDE?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, constructor, stack

By using typdef i have defines Stack, but the code blocks gives me an error
while i call the object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Stack
{
    int data[20];
    int top;
};
```

In this class, `Stack *s` is called and when i run the program it gives an error that "s" maybe used uninitialised.
whereas i have initilaised it using constructor.

```
class stackop
{
public:

    Stack *s;

    stackop()
    {
        s->top= -1; //constructor is giving error.
    }

    bool stack_empty();
    bool stack_full();
    void push();
    void pop();
    void display();
};

bool stackop::stack_empty()
{
    if(s->top == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

bool stackop::stack_full()
{
    if(s->top == 19)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
} 

void stackop::push()
{

    if(!stack_full())
    {
        s->top=s->top + 1;
        cout<<"\n Enter an element: ";
        cin>>s->data[s->top];
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n THE STACK IS ALREADY FULL";
    }
}

void stackop::pop()
{
    if(!stack_empty())
    {
        cout<<"\n The value deleted or poped is "<<s->data[s->top];
        s->top=s->top-1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n STACK IS ALREADY EMPTY";
    }
}

void stackop::display()
{
    cout<<"\n The stack is as follows...";
    for(int i=s->top; i>=0; i--)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<s->data[i];
    }
}
```

Also this code runs fine on cpp.sh but terminates the terminal of code blocks returning a garbage value.

```
int main()
{
    int y;
    char ch;

    stackop s1;

    do
    {
        cout<<"\n 1. PUSH.";
        cout<<"\n 2. POP.";
        cout<<"\n 3. Display stack.";
        cout<<"\n\n Enter your choice :: ";
        cin>>y;

        switch(y)
        {
        case 1:
            s1.push();
            break;
        case 2:
            s1.pop();
            break;
        case 3:
            s1.display();
            break;
        }

        cout<<"\n Do you want to continue? : ";
        cin>>ch;

    } while(ch=='y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say, you've initialized the member pointer `s`, but you haven't. With `s->top` you are dereferencing a nullptr. That's UB.

Comment: Not a nullptr. `s` is not initialized at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make small change in your program it will work fine

```
Stack *s = new Stack;
```

by doing above change ,program worked in code block IDE

Comment: Just fine, plus a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an uninitialized pointer (`s`).

```
Stack *s;

stackop()
{
    s->top= -1; //constructor is giving error.
}
```

Here you're accessing a random location in memory.

Maybe you can fix it by not using a pointer

```
Stack s;

stackop()
{
    s.top= -1;
}
```